# Silent Google sign in: why dialog is shown after choosing account

Tags: android, google-signin

I have problem with implementing "Google sign in" in Android App. The code looks like this:

```
            GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(MainActivity.this, gso);

            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> googleSignInAccountTask = signInClient.silentSignIn();

            if (googleSignInAccountTask.isSuccessful()) {
                // There's immediate result available.
                GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount = googleSignInAccountTask.getResult();
            } else {
                // There's no immediate result ready, displays some progress indicator and waits for the
                // async callback.
                googleSignInAccountTask.addOnCompleteListener((OnCompleteListener) task -> {
                    try {
                        GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount = (GoogleSignInAccount) task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                    } catch (Exception apiException) {
                        Intent signInIntent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
                        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 12123);
                    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }
```

Expected behaviour:
1. User opens app for the first time. 
2. "Google sign in" dialog with accounts to choose opens. User choose account.
2. User closes app and opens again. Since account is chosen silent sign in works and user account is available without user interaction.

However, each time app is started dialog with accounts to choose is shown. After app is restarted "googleSignInAccountTask.isSuccessful()" always return false. This "silentSignIn()" is not working.

I do not want to show this dialog every time app starts. Any hints how to achieve it? iOS SDK works as expected. It somehow remembers that account was selected.

Comment: Any ideas? The behavious is really strange.

Answer (score 0):

where are you handling onActivityResult of first time sign-in? Add following code might solve problem. Also re-check scope of variable signInAccount.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int mRequestCode, int mResultCode, Intent mIntentData) {
    super.onActivityResult(mRequestCode, mResultCode, mIntentData);
    if (mRequestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(mIntentData);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> mCompletedTask) {
    try {
        signInAccount = mCompletedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

    } catch (ApiException e) { ...        }
```